# Residual widgets shadow effects when moving within kivymd app screens

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Hello to all the comunity members, I apologise if in my previous post i have provided incomplete information about the problem. i'm new to this platform and i'm also new programming. designing my application layout with kivymd i'm facing with a very weird issue with widget shadow when moving from a screen to another, when i change screen it seems that some widgets leave their shadow anchored to the background and cannot get rid of them. the picture show this issue. i wish somoone have already faced this problem and could give me some advices on how to get rid of this weird effect.

in order to try to fix the problem i've tried to remove any kind of property to the widgets, from elevation to shadow effects, but the situation is still unchanged.
i'm not allowed yet to insert pictures, it will describe better the nature of the problem, but I have attached a link to the image instead.

```
                        GridLayout:
                            cols:1
                            MDLabel:
                                size_hint: (1,.1)
                                text: "Table Title\nSESSION TYPE SUMMARY"

                        MDBoxLayout:
                            orientation: "vertical"
                            size_hint:1,.4
                            spacing: 5
                            FloatLayout:
                                id:table
                                anchor_left:True
                                bar_width: 2
                            BoxLayout:
                                elevation: 0
                                orientation:"horizontal"
                                size_hint:(1, .5)
                                spacing:10
                                MDRaisedButton:
                                    elevation: 0

                                    id: tab_period
                                    pos_hint: {"center_y": .1}
                                    size_hint: (.5, .3)
                                    text:"suca"
                                    on_release: root.table_menu_period()
                                MDRaisedButton:
                                    elevation: 0

                                    background_normal: ''
                                    id:sess_type
                                    pos_hint: {"center_y": .1}
                                    size_hint: (.5, .3)
                                    text:"suca2"
                                    on_release: root.table_menu_session()
                        BoxLayout:

                            orientation: "vertical"
                            # size_hint_y: .5
                            # pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
```

[link to the image: the buttons leave a shadow into the screen while scrolling both direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5hmp.png)

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also met the same issue. In short, try to add a line like this between your remove_widget and add-widget.

```
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.button_layout.canvas.ask_update(), 0)
```

Seems like it is related to the kivy's remove_widget mechanism. When you remove a widget and then add it back, Kivy doesn't necessarily immediately update the graphical representation of the parent widget. This can sometimes result in a "shadow" of the removed widget still appearing on the screen.

One possible solution is to schedule the addition of the widget to the next frame using Clock.schedule_once. This will ensure that the widget is added after the removal has been fully processed.

Comment: If not working try not to use RaisedButton

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in my case the problem was with the type of the buttons used. Changing the buttons type the problem was gone